# stuck with producing a query for this?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Employee number 99 has phoned in sick.   We need the full details of his supervisor.

I have an employee table with "empno", "name", "date_of_birth", "address", "postcode", "cinema_no", "super_empno" as fields.

Employee number 99's supervisor is the details of the "super_empno" which is also in employee table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE empno = (SELECT super_empno FROM employee WHERE empno = 99)
```

Comment: Trying to answer this as well: Write a SQL statement to count the number of films in the database released before August 2016. 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of films released before August 2016 " FROM FILM; WHERE date_of_release < date '2016-08-01';
however get this error:
Error starting at line : 18 in command - WHERE date_of_release < date '2016-08-01' Error report - Unknown Command

Comment: You have an extra semicolon after your FROM statement, otherwise that query should probably work

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a self join:

I have created following table:

```
create table table1("empno" int, "name"  varchar(33), "super_empno" int);
insert into table1 values(1, "Bob", 5);
insert into table1 values(2, "Megan", 7);
insert into table1 values(3, "Poul", 5);
insert into table1 values(4, "Eva", 6);
insert into table1 values(5, "Zane", 2);
insert into table1 values(6, "Ibrogim", 7);
insert into table1 values(99, "Nikolaus", 1);
```

As result data looks like this:

```
1|Bob|5
2|Megan|7
3|Poul|5
4|Eva|6
5|Zane|2
6|Ibrogim|7
99|Nikolaus|1
```

Supervisor for user 99 is user 1. To get information about 99th user's  supervisor you need to do the self-join on a table1:

```
select b.* from table1 a, table1 b where a.empno=99 and a.super_empno = b.empno;
```

Result:

```
1|Bob|5
```